# Missing apps tab in iTunes

Tags: iphone

Where is my apps tab in itunes (ver 12.7.3)?

I am actually trying to find an app called RFK WiFi to change the settings but it does not appear in Settings app list of apps.  I thought I could change it on my PC in Itunes.  Now I learn I do not have an apps tab in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

The Apps functionality was removed from iTunes in version 12.7, so you cannot access that from iTunes anymore.

However if the app does not have a setting in the Settings app on the device, it was not going to show up in iTunes before 12.7 either.

- [How to restore apps on iPod?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319677/)
- [How do I backup and restore my IPA app backups in iTunes 12.7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298307/)

Comment: @bmike He's not looking to restore apps. He's looking to change a setting for an app - different thing.